# Show Databases names with PDO, mysql and pgsql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

how can I get the list of databases using PDO?
I found in a topic this for Mysql:

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$server = 'localhost';

$dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$server", $user, $pass );
$dbs = $dbh->query( 'SHOW DATABASES' );
```

Can i use "`query( 'SHOW DATABASES' )`" with postgresql too?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Postgresql` use:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database
```